# Как можно установить соединение Wi-Fi direct на Android без подтверждения подключения?

Tags: java, android, p2p

Привет всем!

Предупрежу сразу что в андроидах я не силен. Есть 2 устройства: одно у меня в руках, другое вне досягаемости, например на авиамодели. Мне нужно организовать взаимодействие этих устройств: они подключаются с помощью wi-fi direct и обмениваются данными.

Подключение удалось организовать, но тут возникла проблема: при запросе на подключение, одно из устройств выдает окошко и спрашивает об этом пользователя. Пока пользователь не подтвердит подключение окошко будет висеть. Нужно как-то избавиться от этого окошка, но вот как?